# What Type of Network Connection for IP for Nautlus

Tags: wireless, networking

I am using LTS 14.

I am trying to figure out how to Network a device.

I don't know what kind of network it is for a location of: **10.10.10.254** with a **username/password**. Does anyone know what type it is so I can access it in Nautilus?

I already used windows to create a network based off the IP Address very easily.

This is for a **RAVPower FileHub** *Wireless SD Card Reader, Wireless External HDD/Flash Drive Media sharing, Built-in 3000mAh External Battery Pack,Wireless USB,Wireles*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an internal router IP-adreess, but also depends on your ISP can also have a wierd firewall gateway that prevents you from accessing stuff or get hacked but. but most probable its your router. 
Most Common internal IP-ranges are:

192.168.#.#

10.#.#.#

(#)= number between 0-255

go on google and search "what's my IP" without quote then if you get a different IP there then you really know that this IP you have is an internal one..

FYI install samba too on Ubuntu so you can share in between linux and Windows shares too.

Good luck to you hope it resolves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

10.10.10.254 is the address which is created when you connect to the wifi of the rav power.

You can access to it by using firefox or chrome.